# How to use a variable for the key part of a map

Tags: groovy

Let's say I have

```
def A = "abc"
def X = "xyz"
```

how do I create a `Map` where, instead of

```
def map = [A:1, X:2]
```

I get instead the equivalent of writing

```
def map = [abc:1, xyz:2]
```

but can use a variables `A` and `X` for the key?

P.S.:  Same question for the value part of the map.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Use this:

```
def map = [(A):1, (X):2]
```

For the value-part it's even easier, since there is no automagic "convert text to string" happening:

```
def map = [keyA:A, keyX:X]
```

Comment: Just to provide a reference: the [Map Documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps) says: `To use the value of a String as the key value of a map, simply surround the variable with parenthesis.`

Comment: @mmigdol this quote is from [old groovy documentation](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps.html) in the [newest documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Maps) its like this: 
`Map keys are strings by default: [a:1] is equivalent to ['a':1]. This can be confusing if you define a variable named a and that you want the value of  to be the key in your map. If this is the case, then you must escape >the key by adding parenthesis..`

Comment: So what is the diff between 
def map = [(A):1, (X):2] .  and def map = ["$A":1, (X):2] if any?

Comment: @TriMix the difference is Strings vs GStrings. With `[(A):1, (X):2]`, the variable is being escaped into a String. With `["$A":1, (X):2]`, the `"$A"` is an interpolated string which results in a GString. Maps expect the keys to be immutable which a GString doesn't provide.

Answer (score 28):

Further to [Joachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750342/how-to-use-a-variable-for-the-key-part-of-a-map/7750373#7750373), if you want to add entries to an existing map and the keys are variables, use:

```
def map = [:]
def A = 'abc'
map[A] = 2
```

If you use:

```
map.A = 2
```

It is assumed that you want to use the literal string 'A' as the key (even though there is a variable named A in scope.

### Update

As @tim_yates pointed out in a comment, a key variable will also be resolved if you use:

```
map."$A" = 2
```

though personally I prefer to use the `[A]` syntax because refactoring tools might miss the `"$A"` reference if the variable is renamed

Comment: the `map."$A"` syntax gives you the benefit of null safe map navigation with `map?."$A"`, which AFAIK you cannot achieve using `map[A]` syntax

Comment: What would map?."$A" = 2 mean when map is null? Is that interesting?

Comment: map["$A"] works

Comment: `map."$A" = 2` works great in Jenkins pipelines as well. `map.A` didn't worked.