# Using Longs as Keys in Groovy Map

Tags: groovy

I want a Map to contain numeric mappings, I do:

```
Long long1 = 44l;
Long long2 = 45l;

def myMap = [long1: 26, long2: 27];

println(myMap)
```

But what is outputted is:

```
[long1:26, long2:27]
```

I want it to be:

```
[44: 26, 45: 27]
```

And I need to do this through variables, as I don't know what the values will be until runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: Groovy does that for all variables (not only Long). If we want to use the value as key then syntax mentioned in answer has to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your map declaration to the following:

```
def myMap = [(long1): 26, (long2): 27]
```

Groovy is doing some implicit variable-name-to-String conversion when you declare your Map, so instead of it evaluating `long1` it is using `long1` as a String key name. Also see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750342/how-to-use-a-variable-for-the-key-part-of-a-map).