# How to use variable in Key Names in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

The trick in [How to use a variable for the key part of a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750342/how-to-use-a-variable-for-the-key-part-of-a-map) is not working for the following.

How to make it work?

```
def x = [users:[[name:'Alice', age:30], [name:'Bob', age:25]], settings:[app:[name:'ExampleApp', version:'1.0.0']]]
println x

def userNameKey = "users[0].name"
def appVersionKey = "settings.app.version"

def firstUserName = x."(userNameKey)" // Accesses "users[0].name"
println "First user's name: ${firstUserName}"

def appVer = x."$appVersionKey" // Accesses "settings.app.version"
println "App version: ${appVer}"
```

BTW, for the curious mind, the above "solution" comes from Google Gemini --

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**unsafe but the easiest way to evaluate dynamic expression - [Eval.me](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#me(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String))**

```
def x = [
      users:[
        [name:'Alice', age:30], 
        [name:'Bob', age:25]], 
      settings:[app:[name:'ExampleApp', version:'1.0.0']]
]

def userNameKey = "ROOT.users[0].name"
def appVersionKey = "ROOT.settings.app.version"

def firstUserName = Eval.me("ROOT", x, userNameKey)
println "First user's name: ${firstUserName}"

def appVer = Eval.me("ROOT", x, appVersionKey)
println "App version: ${appVer}"
```

prints:

```
First user's name: Alice
App version: 1.0.0
```

> This option is unsafe because if evaluation expression provided by 3dr party - they could read/write almost anything from your system...

---

**option 2 - use jsonpath**

read more about jsonpath sysntax here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

```
@Grab(group='com.jayway.jsonpath', module='json-path', version='2.9.0')
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

def x = [
      users:[
        [name:'Alice', age:30], 
        [name:'Bob', age:25]], 
      settings:[app:[name:'ExampleApp', version:'1.0.0']]
]

def userNameKey = '$.users[0].name'
def appVersionKey = '$.settings.app.version'

def xJPath = JsonPath.parse(x)

def firstUserName = xJPath.read(userNameKey)
println "First user's name: ${firstUserName}"

def appVer = xJPath.read(appVersionKey)
println "App version: ${appVer}"
```

Comment: Be careful though... If `userNameKey` is supplied by a user, this could be a security risk

Comment: Oh, much difficult than my impression, which comes from google Gemini. OP updated to include that (missing) part, . Thanks for the answer.